# Entity Framework Migrationbuilder.CreateTable Skipping Model Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.net 2.0 App using MVC and EF Core. Im just in the beginning stages of putting all the data together(and I am new to coding) so there may be some bad practices or things I could do better.

I have an Employee model class that inherits from a SiteUser model class. Right not they are pretty simple classes. When I use EF migration for the first initial migration, the generated code is not creating a CreateTable method for the Employee Class.The Employee Class is in the Snapshot file, but not in the create table.

Does anything in these classes stick out as to why they would not generate?
I have removed EF from project, and reinstalled without any success.

SiteUser model class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Intranet_MVC_Core.Models
{
    public class SiteUser : Person
    {
        public string ObjectIdentifier { get; set; }
        public SiteUserStatus SiteUserStatus { get; set; }
        public UserType UserType { get; set; }
        public string PhotoURL { get; set; }

        public string StartupPage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Employee Model Class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Intranet_MVC_Core.Models
{
    public class Employee : SiteUser
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string WorkMobile { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string EmergencyContact { get; set; }
        public string EmergencyContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmergencyContactRelationship { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string InOutMemo { get; set; }
        public DateTime InOutReturnTime { get; set; }
        public String InOutLocation { get; set; }

        public string AlternateEmail { get; set; }
        public string PersonalEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }

        public bool ProjectManager { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        //Foreign Key
        public virtual EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }

        public virtual EmployeeTitle EmployeeTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual InOutStatus InOutStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DBContext Class (// Generates in EF Migration, //x Does not generate

```
using Intranet_MVC_Core.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Intranet_MVC_Core.Context
{
    public class CRMContext : DbContext
    {
        public CRMContext()
        {
        }

        public CRMContext(DbContextOptions<CRMContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ActivityCode> ActivityCodes { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<ActivityItem> ActivityItem { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Alert> Alerts { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<AlertStatus> AlertStatuses { get; set; } //
        public DbSet<AlertType> AlertTypes { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<AppSetting> AppSettings { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<CompanyType> CompanyTypes { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<ContactStatus> ContactStatuses { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Correspondence> Correspondences { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<Deliverable> Deliverables { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }//x Not Generating in EF Migration Code
        public DbSet<EmployeeTitle> EmployeeTitles { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<EmployeeType> EmployeeTypes { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<EventAssignment> EventAssignments { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<EventTask> EventTasks { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<EventType> EventTypes { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<InOutStatus> InOutStatuses { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<JobStatus> JobStatuses { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<ProposalActivity> JobScopes { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<Lead> Leads { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<MarketingStep> MarketingSteps { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<NewsPost> NewsPosts { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<NewsPostTag> NewsPostTags { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<ProjectType> ProjectTypes { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Proposal> Proposals { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<Prospect> Prospects { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<ActivityItem> ProposalScopeItems { get; set; }//x Not Generating in EF Migration Code
        public DbSet<Prefix> Prefixes { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<SalesCampaign> SalesCompaigns { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<SalesMaterial> SalesMaterials { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<SalesType> SalesType { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<SiteUser> SiteUser { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<SiteUserStatus> SiteUserStatuses { get; set; }//
        public DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }//

        public DbSet<WorkAssignment> WorkAssignments { get; set; }//
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Inheritance (Relational Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance) - table-per-hierarchy (TPH) topic.

Comment: Check what it's generating for the `SiteUser` class. As per @IvanStoev it may be pulling all the properties into that table.

Comment: So, I removed the Siteuser from the DBContext class and employee table is now being added. When using Inheritance, and the inherited class is also a DBset, i have to employee TPT, or Create a new class that Inherits SiteUser, and keep SiteUser out of the DBContext. -Thank you both!